# Shuffle words' characters while maintaining sentence structure and punctuations

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, algorithm, shuffle

So, I want to be able to scramble words in a sentence, but:

- Word order in the sentence(s) is left the same.
- If the word started with a capital letter, the jumbled word must also start with a capital letter
  (i.e., the first letter gets capitalised).
- Punctuation marks . , ; ! and ? need to be preserved.

For instance, for the sentence "Tom and I watched Star Wars in the cinema, it was
fun!" a jumbled version would be "Mto nad I wachtde Tars Rswa ni het amecin, ti wsa
fnu!".

```
from random import shuffle

def shuffle_word(word):
    word = list(word)
    if word.title():
        ????   #then keep first capital letter in same position in word?
    elif char == '!' or '.' or ',' or '?':
        ????  #then keep their position?
    else:
        shuffle(word)
    return''.join(word)
L = input('try enter a sentence:').split()
print([shuffle_word(word) for word in L])
```

I am ok for understanding how to jumble each word in the sentence but... struggling with the if statement to apply specifics? please help!

Comment: How should the apostrophes be handled? For example if the word is `it's`, or `It's` considering the shuffled version can be `'tis`, what happens to the capitalization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code. Little different from your logic. Feel free to optimize the code.

```
import random

def shuffle_word(words):
    words_new = words.split(" ")
    out=''
    for word in words_new:
        l = list(word)
        if word.istitle():
            result = ''.join(random.sample(word, len(word)))
            out = out + ' ' + result.title()
        elif any(i in word for i in ('!','.',',')):
            result = ''.join(random.sample(word[:-1], len(word)-1))
            out = out + ' ' + result+word[-1]
        else:
            result = ''.join(random.sample(word, len(word)))
            out = out +' ' + result
    return (out[1:])
L = "Tom and I watched Star Wars in the cinema, it was fun!"
print(shuffle_word(L))
```

Output of above code execution:

```
Mto nda I whaecdt Atsr Swra in hte ienamc, ti wsa nfu!
```

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: oh thank you so much!  I am just a beginner so I find it always interesting to see how others approach :) much appreciated :)

Comment: Glad it helped. All the best exploring Python.

Answer (score 1):

Glad to see you've figured out most of the logic.

To maintain the capitalization of the first letter, you can check it beforehand and capitalize the "new" first letter later.

```
first_letter_is_cap = word[0].isupper()

shuffle(word)

if first_letter_is_cap:
    # Re-capitalize first letter
    word[0] = word[0].upper()
```

To maintain the position of a trailing punctuation, strip it first and add it back afterwards:

```
last_char = word[-1]
if last_char in ".,;!?":
    # Strip the punctuation
    word = word[:-1]

shuffle(word)

if last_char in ".,;!?":
    # Add it back
    word.append(last_char)
```

Comment: thank you so much! Interesting approach, didn't think of actually adding them back in like this :) I've definitely learned something here that will help me progress with future problem solving in python :)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a string processing algorithm I would consider using regular expressions. Regex gives you more flexibility, cleaner code and you can get rid of the conditions for edge cases. For example this code handles apostrophes, numbers, quote marks and special phrases like date and time, without any additional code and you can control these just by changing the pattern of regular expression.

```
from random import shuffle
import re

# Characters considered part of words
pattern = r"[A-Za-z']+"

# shuffle and lowercase word characters
def shuffle_word(word):
    w = list(word)
    shuffle(w)
    return ''.join(w).lower()

# fucntion to shuffle word used in replace
def replace_func(match):
    return shuffle_word(match.group())

def shuffle_str(str):
    # replace words with their shuffled version
    shuffled_str = re.sub(pattern, replace_func, str)

    # find original uppercase letters
    uppercase_letters = re.finditer(r"[A-Z]", str)

    # make new characters in uppercase positions uppercase
    char_list = list(shuffled_str)
    for match in uppercase_letters:
        uppercase_index = match.start()
        char_list[uppercase_index] = char_list[uppercase_index].upper()

    return ''.join(char_list)

print(shuffle_str('''Tom and I watched "Star Wars" in the cinema's new 3D theater yesterday at 8:00pm, it was fun!'''))
```

Comment: slightly more difficult approach, but yes interesting to see how regex can be used in this scenario, feel silly I did not think of it :) Thank you so much for your help, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This works with any sentence, even if was "special" characters in a row, preserving all the punctuaction marks:

```py
from random import sample

def shuffle_word(sentence):
  new_sentence=""
  word=""
  for i,char in enumerate(sentence+' '):
    if char.isalpha():
      word+=char
    else:
      if word:
        if len(word)==1:
          new_sentence+=word
        else:
          new_word=''.join(sample(word,len(word)))
          if word==word.title():
            new_sentence+=new_word.title()
          else:
            new_sentence+=new_word
        word=""
      new_sentence+=char
  return new_sentence


text="Tom and I watched Star Wars in the cinema, it was... fun!"

print(shuffle_word(text))
```

Output:

```
Mto nda I hctawed Rast Aswr in the animec, ti asw... fnu!
```